# Why does the position of my JS change my html code?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I didn't know JS position could change the reults of my html page until today. I want the image src to switch between two different url's "on click". Why does this first code work like I want it to but the second one doesn't??? The source html for the second code produces a blank string for the var not_a_bad_word.

1st code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>'Murica!'</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $dbhost = 'databasePlace';
        $dbname = 'mine';
        $dbuser = 'me';
        $dbpass = '*****';

        $link = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
        mysqli_select_db($link, $dbname);
        $name = $_GET["fname"];

        $query = sprintf(
            "SELECT image_url, Type
             FROM Pokemon c
             WHERE c.name = '%s'", 
             mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $name));

        $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($link, $query));

        echo '<img id="pokemon_card" onclick="changeImage()" height="450" 
                  width="330" src="' . $result['image_url'] . '"/>';

        mysqli_close($link);
        ?>
        <script>
            function changeImage() {
                element = document.getElementById('pokemon_card');
                var not_a_bad_word = "<?php echo $result['image_url']; ?>";

                if (element.src == "http://dmisasi.files.wordpress.com/2010/12/david-pokemon-card-back.jpg") {
                    element.src = not_a_bad_word;
                }
                else {
                    element.src="http://dmisasi.files.wordpress.com/2010/12/david-pokemon-card-back.jpg";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

2nd code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>'Murica!</title>
        <script>
            function changeImage() {
                element = document.getElementById('pokemon_card');
                var not_a_bad_word = "<?php echo $result['image_url']; ?>";

                if (element.src == "http://dmisasi.files.wordpress.com/2010/12/david-pokemon-card-back.jpg") {
                    element.src = not_a_bad_word;
                }
                else {
                    element.src="http://dmisasi.files.wordpress.com/2010/12/david-pokemon-card-back.jpg";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $dbhost = 'databasePlace';
        $dbname = 'mine';
        $dbuser = 'me';
        $dbpass = '*****';

        $link = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
        mysqli_select_db($link, $dbname);
        $name = $_GET["fname"];

        $query = sprintf(
            "SELECT image_url, Type
             FROM Pokemon c
             WHERE c.name = '%s'", 
             mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $name));

        $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($link, $query));

        echo '<img id="pokemon_card" onclick="changeImage()" height="450" 
                  width="330" src="' . $result['image_url'] . '"/>';

        mysqli_close($link);
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you show your code to other people, please format it nicely. Code is written only once but read many times so it is worth the extra effort (also it is common courtesy to your fellow programmers). I've formatted the code in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your first example, the PHP code that creates the variables `$result['image_url']` runs *before* the variable is echo'd.

If you look at your second example which produces the blank, `$result['image_url']` is actually only defined *after* it has been echo'd.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because at the point of insertion of the JS code in the second example, the elements 'pokemon_card' are not there yet. Therefore, the selector is not defined and cant be used in the code. It is always advisable to put js code that uses DOM element to be put at the end of the document.

Comment: Also in second example, he doesn't get value of `$result` because it doesn't run PHP before js

Comment: I vote for jQuery `ready` event instead of the end of the document.

Comment: This actually is wrong. Since he runs the function to change the image only after the doc has loaded (only when the image is clicked, thus the element must be available at that point), it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: I am not sure why this answer get upvote because main problem is with sequence of execution of PHP code